# ref to form element is null when submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, forms, file-upload, react-hooks, next.js

I have a form that is supposed to upload a file (image) to a NextJs API route. I try to retrieve the form values using a ref to the form. However when I try to access the form in the onSubmit function, the ref is still null. I am aware that refs can be null on first render, but I assume that by the time a form is submitted, the ref should be resolved.

This is what the form looks likes:

```
<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
  <label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
  <input id="image" accept="image/*" multiple={false} onChange={onImageChange} name="image" type="file" required />
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

This is what the rest of the (function) component looks like:

```
const UploadImageModal = (): JSX.Element => {
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)
  const onFormSubmit = async (event: SubmitEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(formRef.current) //Shows null
    const data = new FormData(formRef.current)
    const res = await fetch('/api/upload-image', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    })
  }
  
  return (/* The component including the form */)
}
```

I am using TypeScript, however I don't think that is relevant, since TypeScript has no influence during runtime. I left out anything that I believe to be irrelevant to this question like styling and the rest of the component that doesn't touch the form.

The API route has been tested using Postman and is working as supposed. If there is a way to get the formdata directly from the SubmitEvent that would also be a good solution. I thought the formdata would be exposed through that event, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Thanks to anyone taking the time to help me out!

Comment: Could you provide the code for the full component? I'm not able to reproduce the issue with the code you provided so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get form DOM reference by

```
const data = new FormData(event.target)
```

[info]
You are using typescript so the type of the handler should be

```
const onFormSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement > = async (event) => {
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works great. However since it does not solve the problem of the missing reference I have not marked the answer as accepted (yet). Also thanks for the extra info. I only recently started using TypeScript with React, so I sometimes forget to type certain things. The production build would have smacked me for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I attached the working code and also Codesandbox below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-form-usage-with-typescript-16ghf?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SyntheticEvent, useRef } from "react";

const UploadImageModal = (): JSX.Element => {
  const formRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLFormElement>;

  const onFormSubmit = async (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(formRef); //Shows null
    const data = new FormData(formRef.current);
    const res = await fetch("/api/upload-image", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data
    });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
      <input
        id="image"
        accept="image/*"
        multiple={false}
        name="image"
        type="file"
        required
      />
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UploadImageModal />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Could you maybe explain what you changed to fix the missing form reference? I only notice some extra/different typing and the extra code to make the example actually run in codesandbox (thanks for which though)

Comment: extra/different typing can be the problem. Can you provide the tsconfig.json?
Also consider your typo like `type="file required />`

Comment: Thanks I fixed the typo. It only existed in the question, not my code, but nice catch. The thing is, when running tsc, it compiles just fine. Once compiled, typescript does nothing anymore and therefore can't cause any runtime error.